# Where can I find good UVI forecasts?

Tags: uv-protection

I normally use weather.gov and/or weather.com for weather forecasts. Neither provides UVI (or at least I can't find it). Also, I rarely go outdoors, so I don't have an intuitive sense of when I get get away without sunscreen. I hate both sunburns and sunscreen, so I have a dilemma when I do need to go outside for extended periods.

Googling finds a few resources, but they mostly provide a UV max, i.e. at noon. Doesn't help if I'm going out for an extended period in the morning/afternoon.

Are there any good sources of hourly-ish UVI forecasts? Alternately, are there detectors I can buy to estimate how long it will take me to burn?

Answer (score 2):

Check out sunburnmap.com.  Just enter your city and you can get results such as this:

[image]

[Accuweather.com](https://www.accuweather.com/) also has some hourly UV forecasts.  You need to click on the hourly forecast for your location and scroll down to the bottom.